# Is there a way to convert GeoTIFF to DEM?

Tags: convert, dem, geotiff-tiff

Simple enough question. The NASA Aster data comes in GeoTIFF format, but the tool I'm using (Sketchup) only accepts DEM. Is there a way to convert?

I did a lot of searching, and only found the program GEOTIFF4, but it's obsolete, it's Windows-only, and source code is not available.

Comment: Have you found any solution to work with geotiff on macos? (especially looking for converting it into a grayscale)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GDAL should be able to convert rasters between any usual formats:

```
gdal_translate -of SRTMHGT input.tif output.hgt
```

See

http://www.gdal.org/gdal_translate.html

http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/gdal-dev-Aster-tif-files-to-hgt-td3742884.html

for more details.

Comment: Has anybody used the gdal package on a Mac? I just installed it (113Mb!) and gdal_translate still doesn't seem to be there.

Comment: Edit -- found the program, thanks to the Mac pkgutil tool. It's installed in /Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Programs/gdal_translate.

Comment: And sigh. All that work, and over 100Mb of installed software, and the resulting .dem files just make Sketchup crash on the spot. Thanks for all your help anyway.